# Array.mean(axis = 1) with a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array with 1000 rows and 10 colums (price_list). With the command

```
price_list.mean(axis = 1)
```

I performed the mean for each row. How can I use a loop to perform the same computation? Thank you very much.

Example:

```
In: price_list
Out: array([[ 88.118629  ,  88.118629  ,  88.118629  , ...,  88.118629  ,
     88.118629  ,  88.118629  ],
   [ 87.89849451,  88.28521857,  87.88550764, ...,  88.63412578,
     88.10322998,  88.88926288],
   [ 88.65587777,  87.76942845,  88.48962856, ...,  88.2796555 ,
     88.63031452,  88.88182671],
   ...,
   [ 65.34289835,  66.92005094,  90.12852383, ..., 167.15607114,
    226.66403648, 130.07803463],
   [ 65.55047596,  66.5069593 ,  88.99919496, ..., 164.45858893,
    229.17325779, 129.15578263],
   [ 64.71865904,  66.40562405,  88.06256922, ..., 161.90378821,
    227.48460064, 127.58404374]])

In: price_list_new = price.list.mean(axis = 1)
Out: array([ 88.118629  ,  88.35964886,  88.36762515,  88.82571439,
    89.15239399,  88.74944235,  88.82604126,  88.48155552,
    88.70669718,  88.87349793,  88.49569989,  88.3928375 ,
    88.44854633,  88.38734393,  88.51877214,  88.53055382,
    88.47660207,  88.08328303,  88.05407612,  87.73566519,
    88.10523588,  87.72906819,  87.53641688,  87.5564761 ,
    87.4484196 ,  .............])
```

Comment: The whole point of using a vectorized approach is to avoid using loop? Why do you want to do that? Also, have you tried anything yet? what's wrong with your code if you've tried anything already?

Comment: Could you share an example of your input with corresponding output?

Comment: I want to use loop to learn how can I perform the same operation without using the command, It is only a way to enhance my knolwdeges.

Comment: You aren't going to learn much from something this counter productive if someone writes the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

First I create a fake `price_list`:

```
import numpy as np
price_list = np.random.rand(10,1000)
price_list.mean(axis = 1)
#> array([0.49730006, 0.48494404, 0.4948243 , 0.49762745, 0.49727592,
#>     0.50856465, 0.4993344 , 0.49325429, 0.4938947 , 0.50599995])
```

Now, we can do it looping once using vectorized arrays:

```
price_list_mean = np.zeros(10)
for i in range(price_list.shape[1]):
    price_list_mean = price_list_mean + price_list[:,i]
price_list_mean = price_list_mean/price_list.shape[1]

# Checking the solution
np.isclose(price_list_mean,price_list.mean(axis = 1))
#> array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Or we can do it using a double loop:

```
price_list_mean = np.zeros(10)
for j in range(price_list.shape[0]):
    for i in range(price_list.shape[1]):
        price_list_mean[j] = price_list_mean[j] + price_list[j,i]
    price_list_mean[j] = price_list_mean[j] / price_list.shape[1]

# Checking the solution
np.isclose(price_list_mean,price_list.mean(axis = 1))
#> array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

WARNING!: These solutions are much more inefficient than just computing the mean with a function. They shouldn't be used unless for didactic purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
price_list.mean(axis = 1)
# array([ 3.5, 11.5, 19.5, 27.5, 35.5])
```

The same can be done by, iterating thru the numpy array and calculate the mean of each row.

```
for i in price_list:
    print(i.mean())
```

or

```
[i.mean() for i in price_list]
```